# how to recover tabs from a firefox on linux which is unresponsive to mouse or keyboard actions, but only scroll up and down on single tab

Tags: linux, firefox, unresponsive

I opened up around 50 tabs in a single firefox Private Window on Linux and all was good and fast,
I then opened another URL in a new tab, which asked me to Stop or Wait for unresponsive script running, where I chose to Stop. Then it started behaving abnormally; I was only able to do the following:

- scroll on the tab using either middle mouse button or [Up] [Down] key on keyboard
  jfie
- right click the tab content to open up right-click menu,
- hover over the icons and change their background color like Homepage, Refresh, Page Actions, Show sidebars, as well as display their lables;

but I was not able to

- trigger the proper response from above buttons, or
- switch to another tab
- close or create any tab

I noticed in journalctl logs around the time frame this happend, which showed the following:

```
<date> <hour>:<minute>:30 <hostname> dbus-daemon[744]: [session uid=1000 pid=744] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1249 comm="firefox ")

<date> <hour>:<minute>:33 <hostname> dbus-daemon[744]: [session uid=1000 pid=744] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'

<date> <hour>:<minute>:33 <hostname> org.gnome.gedit[744]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

<date> <hour>:<minute>:33 <hostname> gedit[30517]: cannot open display: 

<date> <hour>:<minute>:34 <hostname> dbus-daemon[744]: [session uid=1000 pid=744] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1249 comm="firefox ")

<date> <hour>:<minute>:34 <hostname> dbus-daemon[744]: [session uid=1000 pid=744] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'

<date> <hour>:<minute>:34 <hostname> org.gnome.gedit[744]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

<date> <hour>:<minute>:34 <hostname> unknown[30517]: cannot open display: 

<date> <hour>:<minute>:39 <hostname> dbus-daemon[744]: [session uid=1000 pid=744] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1249 comm="firefox ")

<date> <hour>:<minute>:39 <hostname> dbus-daemon[744]: [session uid=1000 pid=744] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'

<date> <hour>:<minute>:39 <hostname> org.gnome.gedit[744]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

<date> <hour>:<minute>:39 <hostname> gedit[30517]: cannot open display:
```

NOTE that I did not open any gedit intentionally during that time window.

So far, I have not closed the unresponsive window, in hope that I would be able to restore those tabs. But I am not sure where to start. The $HOME/.mozilla/firefox director is about 100MB.

Could anyone help? I am willing to provide any more information and I am willing to invest my time on this.

Thanks.

Comment: No guarantee, but I typically open a console window and "killall Firefox". When I reopen Firefox it tries to restore my tabs. It often has a lot of older previously closed tabs though.

Comment: But I thought it would only reopen regular Window, would it also reopen Private Window?